# innerHTML update value but HTML rendering isn't changed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I misunderstand a JS Behavior, I want to update a td content in my HTML. So I created an anchor with `onclick` attribute.

When I update `.innerHTML`, the content is updated on javascript side, but is not rendered. I don't understand why.

```
<td class="data" id="<?php echo 'data_'.$_data['code']; ?>">A value</td>
```

```
document.getElementById("data_sku").innerHTML = "myNewValue";
```

After this, my HTML rendering doesn't change but when I use

```
document.getElementById("data_sku").textContent
```

I get `"myNewValue"`;

I'm not comfortable with JS/Ajax behavior, just I don't understand why in this case, it's not working but in some other cases, it works.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("data_sku")`

Comment: 1. Too many misprints in the question's code. 2. [mcve] without php, please. 3. Multiple elements with same id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I think that you have multiple elements with the same id in the document.**

In such case you are changing and getting by the script only the first of them, but on the screen you can be looking on the other one, so see no changes observable from script.

```js
document.getElementById("data_sku").innerHTML = "New content";
console.log(document.getElementById("data_sku").textContent);
```

```html
<div id="data_sku" style="display: none;">First</div>
<div id="data_sku">Second</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, I found in the HTML code another occurrence of this id.